# Should I use a callback or some kind of event in Android?

Tags: android

I am just starting to learn Android Development. I have a method that loads an external XML file, and parses the data. How do I tell the caller that the data is parsed and ready? Should I and a callback argument to the method? Or should the caller register to listen to some kind of event, that I can fire when the data is ready?

A code example or links would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [ASyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) class for this kind of problem. It has several methods that you can override that will suit you for most of the tasks you need - for example it has pre-execution method and progress update method.

[Here](http://www.screaming-penguin.com/node/7746) is a tutorial for using ASyncTask in an app.

Answer (score 2):

If the task is not very complex, you could also use the [usual threading approach](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/commontasks.html#threading).

Answer (score 0):

You can always start your activity when the previous work... here parsing the data is done. Alternatively use a broadcast and let your application have a broadcast receiver and notify your application.